# Is thread-local storage persisted between backgroundworker invocations?

Tags: c#, .net, multithreading, backgroundworker, thread-local

Are backgroundworker threads re-used?

Specifically, if I set a named data slot (thread-local storage) during the DoWork() method of a backgroundworker, will the value of that data slot persist, potentially to be found be some other thread at a later time?

I wouldn't have thought so, but I have this bug...

EDIT: [This blog post](http://cs.rthand.com/blogs/blog_with_righthand/archive/2006/05/26/725.aspx) suggests that [BackGroundWorker](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.componentmodel.backgroundworker.aspx) utilises a [ThreadPool](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx), which implies that Threads *are* re-used.  So the question becomes; do re-used threads potentially persist thread-local storage between invocations?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

When the thread pool reuses a thread, it does not clear the data in thread local storage or in fields that are marked with the ThreadStaticAttribute attribute. Therefore, data that is placed in thread local storage by one method can be exposed to any other method that is executed by the same thread pool thread. A method that accesses a field that is marked with the ThreadStaticAttribute attribute could encounter different data depending on which thread pool thread executes it.

> source :
>   http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threading.threadpool.aspx
>
> https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadpool?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=netframework-4.8#remarks

Answer (score -1):

Would need to check the source (or via Reflector) to determine this if it is not specified in MSDN.

If it isn't specified you can't rely on the current behaviour not changing in a future version of .NET.

Edit: Looks like it is using the thread pool, so threads *will* be reused.