# ThreadStatic v.s. ThreadLocal<T>: is generic better than attribute?

Tags: c#, generics, attributes, thread-local, threadstatic

`[ThreadStatic]` is defined using attribute while `ThreadLocal<T>` uses generic. 
Why different design solutions were chosen? 
What are the advantages and disadvantages of using generic over attributes in this case?

Comment: See http://reedcopsey.com/2009/11/12/thread-specific-data-becomes-easier-in-net-4-0-via-threadlocalt/ - I don't see what this has to do with reflection though...

Answer (score 131, accepted):

Something the blog post noted in the comments doesn't make explicit, but I find to be very important, is that `[ThreadStatic]` doesn't automatically initialize things for every thread. For example, say you have this:

```
[ThreadStatic]
private static int Foo = 42;
```

The first thread that uses this will see `Foo` initialized to `42`. But subsequent threads will not. The initializer works for the first thread only. So you end up having to write code to check if it's initialized.

`ThreadLocal<T>` solves that problem by letting you supply an initialization function (as Reed's blog shows) that's run before the first time the item is accessed.

In my opinion, there is no advantage to using `[ThreadStatic]` instead of `ThreadLocal<T>`.

Comment: Except perhaps that [`ThreadLocal<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243(v=vs.110).aspx) is available in .NET 4 and up, and [the `ThreadStatic` attribute](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute(v=vs.100).aspx) is also available in 3.5 and below.

Comment: And if you're not using initializers to set the value, but are instead setting it at some later point after initialization, using [ThreadStatic] is syntactically cleaner.

Comment: `[ThreadStatic]` has the advantage of not having to change existing references to that field in code.

Comment: And except that `ThreadLocal<T>` implements `IDisposable` and usually forces you to implement `IDisposable` as well, which forces your callers to dispose you and therefore implement `IDisposable` as well ...

Comment: By the way: is the `ThreadLocal` initialized when the thread comes from the thread pool? Otherwise it wouldn't be very useful, because it would take data from another thread over. (`[ThreadStatic]` is not initialized when the thread is coming from the pool, but there the expectations are low ...)

Comment: @StefanSteinegger: I would be very careful using `ThreadLocal` or `ThreadStatic` with pool threads. Those values will remain through the entire life of the pool thread, not just for the task that you assign it. That can cause you trouble in some pretty non-obvious ways. See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/561518/is-thread-local-storage-persisted-between-backgroundworker-invocations and similar questions for more info.

Comment: Shouldn't the field in the example also be declared `static`? See https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute(v=vs.110).aspx

Comment: ThreadLocal<> seems to be slightly slower compared to ThreadStatic.

Comment: @Mehran: Slower in what way? Are you saying that access to a variable defined with `ThreadLocal<>` is slower than access to a variable defined with `ThreadStatic`? That seems pretty odd. Do you have a program I can run to test and verify this?

Comment: If you look at the implementation of ThreadLocal (https://github.com/dotnet/coreclr/blob/master/src/mscorlib/src/System/Threading/ThreadLocal.cs) you see it's using ThreadStatic behind the scene. This is a naive benchmark https://pastebin.com/Ym55kZi9

Comment: @Mehran: So I guess the moral of the story is that if you're worried about a few microseconds here and there, you probably should use an instance variable or `ThreadStatic`.

Answer (score 44):

ThreadStatic Initialize only on first thread, ThreadLocal Initialize for each thread. Below is the simple demonstration:

```
    public static ThreadLocal<int> _threadlocal =
        new ThreadLocal<int>(() =>
        {
            return Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        });

    public static void Main()
    {
        new Thread(() =>
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < _threadlocal.Value; x++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("First Thread: {0}", x);
            }
        }).Start();

        new Thread(() =>
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < _threadlocal.Value; x++)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Second Thread: {0}", x);
            }
        }).Start();

        Console.ReadKey();
    }
```

[image]

Answer (score 19):

The main idea behind ThreadStatic is to maintain a *separate copy* of the variable *for each thread*.

```
class Program
    {
        [ThreadStatic]
        static int value = 10;

        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            value = 25;

            Task t1 = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                value++;
                Console.WriteLine("T1: " + value);
            });
            Task t2 = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                value++;
                Console.WriteLine("T2: " + value);
            });
            Task t3 = Task.Run(() =>
            {
                value++;
                Console.WriteLine("T3: " + value);
            });

            Console.WriteLine("Main Thread : " + value);

            Task.WaitAll(t1, t2, t3);
            Console.ReadKey();
        }
    }
```

In the above snippet, we have a separate copy of `value` for each thread, including the main thread.

[image]

So, a ThreadStatic variable will be initialized to its default value on other threads except the thread on which it is created.

If we want to initialize the variable on each thread in our own way, use ThreadLocal.

Comment: And complete article can be found [here](http://putridparrot.com/blog/using-threadstatic-and-threadlocal/).