# Is it good practice to use static methods for generating random numbers?

Tags: c#, .net, random, static

I've written the following code for generating random `float` and `double` numbers.

```
public static class Statics
{
    private static readonly Random random = new Random();
    private static readonly object syncLock = new object();

    public static double getRandomDouble(double min, double max)
    {
        lock (syncLock)
        {
            return random.NextDouble() * (max - min) + min;
        }
    }

    public static float getRandomFloat(float min, float max)
    {
        lock (syncLock)
        {
            return (float)random.NextDouble() * (max - min) + min;
        }
    }
}
```

Is it OK that I'm using `static` `class` and methods for generating random numbers?

My program relies heavily on these methods so I want to make sure that the produced numbers are indeed random. These generators are being used by many objects but not simultaneously.

Comment: Yes, why not? If you just need one Random Generator per class, you can do this.

Comment: Seems fine to me; I don't see a problem.

Comment: As you are using locks, I assume you are using threads. If you are getting a lot of random numbers, this might introduce a bottleneck

Comment: Your question isn't really about random number generators, but about static methods, so maybe edit your question and title? And what is your definition of "ok"?

Comment: _but not simultaneously_ - then why lock?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

There is no reason using `Random` in a static context would be a problem, ***but***, keep in mind (and it seems you did) that ***`Random` is not thread-safe***.

What you chose to do is to synchronize the `Thread`s using `lock`.

You could, however, create a random generator which uses [`ThreadStatic`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.threadstaticattribute(v=vs.110).aspx) or [`ThreadLocal`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd642243(v=vs.110).aspx) (Which is [better for that cause](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26643540/3256506) so you can initialize the instances lazily with different seeds), that way you will earn the performance of not being required to lock.

Also, make sure initializing the `Random` with a different seed for each `Thread` because they might be initialized the same time as you can see on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19271062/3256506) answer:

```
public static class StaticRandom
{
    static int seed = Environment.TickCount;

    static readonly ThreadLocal<Random> random =
        new ThreadLocal<Random>(() => new Random(Interlocked.Increment(ref seed)));

    public static int Rand()
    {
        return random.Value.Next();
    }
}
```