# Rolling a dice with custom amount of faces

Tags: c#

So i am creating a dice using a public class called die. this class has 2 constructors and 3 other methods. When i call class within the main program, it will not print the desired (random) result.

Firstly i am trying to print out a random number between 1-6 based on the default values. Once i figure this out, i would eventually like to specify a number of sides for and print out a number between 1 and this specific number.

```
/// Represents one die (singular of dice) with faces showing values between
/// 1 and the number of faces on the die.
public class Die
{
    private int numFaces, faceValue;
    public Die() => (numFaces, faceValue) = (6, 1);

    public Die(int faces)
    {
        numFaces = faces;

        if (numFaces < 3) 
            numFaces = 6; 
        faceValue = 1; 
    }
    public void RollDie()
    {
        //for (int ctr = 0; ctr <= numFaces; ctr++)
        var rnd = new Random();
        for (int ctr = 1; ctr <= 20; ctr++)
            faceValue = rnd.Next(1, numFaces + 1);
    }
    public int GetFaceValue() => faceValue;
    public int GetNumFaces()  => numFaces;
}
public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        var myDie = new Die(1);
        for (int i =0; i < 20; i++) 
        {
            myDie.RollDie();
            Console.WriteLine(myDie.GetFaceValue());
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You never _roll_ the die. Also, `RollDie` shouldn't take a parameter, your number of faces is already stored in a member variable.

Comment: And in addition to what @tkausl wrote, the RollDie should not create a local instance of the `Random` class. Instead, you should use a field for the `Random` class, so that you can roll the die in a loop and actually get random results every time.

Comment: Some other tips: it is a good idea to not set default 6 when numFaces < 3 is provided. It is a *hidden behaviour*. You should throw a `ArgumentException` with description of the problem. Also, you shouldn't initialize with 1 - it is unexpected. You should either throw exception if it is unitialized, roll dice if unitialized or initialize in constructor. The last one thing: Better `numFaces` optional argument to avoid logic duplication.

Comment: Thanks, i've changed my code based of @tkausl advice. As for the other two suggestions, im not entirely sure how too attempt this

Comment: Creating a new `Random` each time you roll will undoubtedly result in unwanted repeats if you ever invoke in a tight loop.

Comment: This would be a problem.  faces = 1;

Comment: @paparazzo It's like flipping a Möbius coin :-)

Comment: @ParrishHusband Indeed it is, I am unsure of a way around this unwanted repetition tho

Comment: Having well documented code is important, but that doesn't mean comment for the sake of commenting :P In nearly all the cases, you're comments we redundent and I can get the same information from reading the code itself

Answer (score 1):

Since `Random` is time seeded when the parameterless constructor is used, this can have the very negative consequence of duplicating results.

[Excerpt](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.random?view=netframework-4.7.2) from the API documentation:

> However, because the clock has finite resolution, using the
>   parameterless constructor to create different Random objects in close
>   succession creates random number generators that **produce identical
>   sequences of random numbers**.
>
> ...
>
> On most Windows systems, Random objects created within 15 milliseconds of one another are **likely to have identical seed values**.

This is a safer approach in regards to getting random numbers when creating and rolling multiple dice:

```
public class Die
{
    static int seed = Environment.TickCount;
    static readonly ThreadLocal<Random> DieRandom = new ThreadLocal<Random>(() 
        => new Random(Interlocked.Increment(ref seed)));

    public int FaceCount { get; }
    public int Value { get; private set; }

    public Die() : this(6) // default to 6 faces
    {
    }

    public Die(int faceCount)
    {
        if (faceCount < 3) // validate input
            throw new ArgumentOutOfRangeException(nameof(faceCount));

        this.FaceCount = faceCount;
    }

    public int Roll()
    {
        Value = DieRandom.Next(1, FaceCount + 1);
        return Value;
    }
}
```

Edit: updated the Random with thread safety as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270507/correct-way-to-use-random-in-multithread-application).

Comment: One important note, the `Random` class is not thread safe so if you are going to make the variable static you need a lock around the `Random.Next(1, FaceCount)` calling `Next` from multiple threads at the same time can break the class. Also, `Next` has a exclusive upper bound so it would need to be `.Next(1, FaceCount + 1);` or `.Next(0, FaceCount) + 1;`, if you don't do this passing in 6 would give you numbers only in the 1-5 range.

Comment: @ScottChamberlain thanks, that's a great point on thread safety.  Also good spot on the bounds.

Comment: This seems like a much simpler approach. Unfortunately i am unable to change the structure of my code. I have updated my original post with my solution. I am now trying to figure out how to avoid repeated numbers when using the random method. I have set a loop to run the program 20 times and each time it results in the same number being returned. Any ideas on how to prevent this would be appreciated!

Comment: @TomTok is this homework?  Read the linked documentation I posted for the answer to your question.

Comment: Also if you're allowed to, look into how you could overload `Roll` to return multiple rolls.  It's good practice anyway.

Comment: I have followed the links you have provided and have tried many solutions but i still cannot seem to figure it out. here is my current rolldice function: (edit) i will just update the original post too my current code

Comment: @TomTok you can't create a new instance of the `Random` class every time your `RollDie` method is invoked. Think of where you could create it that only gets called once initially.