# How to create object per thread in DataFlow Block but not object per request?

Tags: c#, task-parallel-library, dataflow, tpl-dataflow

I have a sample of code

```cs
var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions();
var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<int>(async request=>{
         var rand = new Ranodm();
         //do some stuff with request by using rand
},options);
```

And the problem with this code is that in every request I have to create new `rand` object. There is a way to define one `rand` object per thread and re-use the same object when handling requests?

Comment: Yeap, a `ThreadLocal<Random>` is the solution. You can take a look at this: [Correct way to use Random in multithread application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19270507/correct-way-to-use-random-in-multithread-application)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to [Reed Copsey for the nice article](http://reedcopsey.com/2009/11/12/thread-specific-data-becomes-easier-in-net-4-0-via-threadlocalt/) and Theodor Zoulias for reminding about `ThreadLocal<T>`.

> The new ThreadLocal class provides us with a strongly typed,
> locally scoped object we can use to setup data that is kept separate
> for each thread.  This allows us to use data stored per thread,
> without having to introduce static variables into our types.
> Internally, the ThreadLocal instance will automatically setup the
> static data, manage its lifetime, do all of the casting to and from
> our specific type.  This makes developing much simpler.

[A msdn  example:](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.threading.threadlocal-1?redirectedfrom=MSDN&view=net-5.0)

```
 // Demonstrates:
    //      ThreadLocal(T) constructor
    //      ThreadLocal(T).Value
    //      One usage of ThreadLocal(T)
    static void Main()
    {
        // Thread-Local variable that yields a name for a thread
        ThreadLocal<string> ThreadName = new ThreadLocal<string>(() =>
        {
            return "Thread" + Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId;
        });

        // Action that prints out ThreadName for the current thread
        Action action = () =>
        {
            // If ThreadName.IsValueCreated is true, it means that we are not the
            // first action to run on this thread.
            bool repeat = ThreadName.IsValueCreated;

            Console.WriteLine("ThreadName = {0} {1}", ThreadName.Value, repeat ? "(repeat)" : "");
        };

        // Launch eight of them.  On 4 cores or less, you should see some repeat ThreadNames
        Parallel.Invoke(action, action, action, action, action, action, action, action);

        // Dispose when you are done
        ThreadName.Dispose();
    }
```

So your code would like this:

```
ThreadLocal<Random> ThreadName = new ThreadLocal<Random>(() =>
{
    return new Random();
});


var options = new ExecutionDataflowBlockOptions
{
    MaxDegreeOfParallelism = 4,
    EnsureOrdered = false,
    BoundedCapacity = 4 * 8
};
var actionBlock = new ActionBlock<int>(async request =>
{
    bool repeat = ThreadName.IsValueCreated;
    var random = ThreadName.Value; // your local random class
    Console.WriteLine($"Thread: {Thread.CurrentThread.ManagedThreadId},  
        repeat: ", repeat ? "(repeat)" : "");

 }, options);
```